# KML Viewer for iOS (any update example?)

Tags: ios, xcode, maps, kml

I´m beginner and I trying to add on a predefined routes on a map application. I have seen the example of Apple's documentation: KMLViewer

It's just what I need, but uses outdated procedures, such as not using ARC (which can be edited) and other functions not well as updating. The advantage would KML me is that I create a file from My Maps in Google, with fully custom route.

I have seen examples (GitHub and Stackoverflow) using alternative libraries, but I get them working.

Do you know of any valid example for at least iOS 7.1 or alternative?